# Accessing previous element in a table without indices

Tags: lua, lua-table

I made a table of floor elements:

```
map.list = {}
--first element
firstfloor = {}
firstfloor.x = 50
firstfloor.y = 800
firstfloor.width = 500
firstfloor.height = screenHeight - firstfloor.y
table insert(map.list,firstfloor)
```

Now i need to make a constructor for next floors. The "x" value is simply previous floor's "x" position + it's width.

```
function map:newFloor(x,y,width)
        local floor = {}
        floor.x = ??? --previous floor's x + previous floor's width
        floor.y = y
        floor.width = width
        floor.height = screenHeight - floor.y
        table.insert(map.list,floor)
        return floor
end
```

As you can see there are no indices here. How can i access previous element's values?

Comment: You can access last inserted floor as `map.list[#map.list]`

Answer (score 3):

When you use `table.insert`, the values *do* have indices (*every* value in a Lua table has an index). They're assigned to the first numeric index available - the length of the array plus 1. In Lua, the `#` operator gives the length of an array-style table:

```
local list = {}
table.insert(list,'foo') -- equivalent to list[1] = 'foo'
table.insert(list,'bar') -- equivalent to list[2] = 'bar'
table.insert(list,'baz') -- equivalent to list[3] = 'baz'
print(#list) -- prints '3'
```

You can access the last value in an array by checking the key at the length of the table, the last value (remember, Lua arrays traditionally start at 1):

```
print(list[#list]) -- prints 'baz'
```

So, to access the previous element's values, you get the last item in the list and check that:

```
local lastfloor = map.list[#map.list]
-- assuming floor is defined somewhere above
floor.x = lastfloor.x + lastfloor.width
```

Pedantic note: If your table has "holes" (`nil` values at numeric indices between two non-`nil` values), concepts like "length" get fuzzy. It doesn't look like that will affect this specific use case, but it comes up.